# Where to obtain a copy of Pick D3?

Tags: pick

I would like to get a copy of Pick D3 and run it on a machine in my lab.  This will be used for software development.  I am working on fraud prevention and dynamic credit models, currently using Java Drools and Learning Classifier Systems.  I see that there are a couple of companies that support some form of Pick D3.  The question is what is the best way to obtain a developer copy of this venerable system?

Answer (score -1):

Pick D3 as far as I understand is now owned/maintained by Rocket Software (they purchased it from Tiger Logic).  There are other branches of Pick & multivalued databases from other companies as well.   I think Rocket Software will allow you to obtain a developer license for free, but you do require a license key for activation.
Contact their support or sales department.   rocketsoftware.com

Comment: The answer to contact Rocket Software Sales is correct, but there is now a cost for D3 to all developers, unlike all of the other MV DBMS platforms.

Answer (score -3):

You can obtain a copy of the D3 without a licence, but only accepts one user and several functions are disabled until you active the system.  To active the system you have to buy at least one licence.